# Javascript reflection - generic toString

Tags: javascript, reflection

now when I put my own Object in alert function I see

> [Object object]

that is pointless information. is there any way using reflection to get all fields and values of those fields?

Answer (score 4):

`JSON.stringify` is often times builtin and can serialize most objects you pass to it.

That said, you should probably just use a debugger or console.log instead of alert-ing things.

Comment: Note that this is not supported in all browsers. This should only be used `if(JSON.stringify)`. So to avoid an error being thrown. Of course, if it is temporary code, you do not need to add this logic, but if the code will persist into production, you may want it so you avoid unexpected failures on IE, or older FF, etc. You may wish to consider using `console` object to get your desired information. But again, only `if(window.console)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of many. But better to use `console.log()` then `alert`

```
function objectToString(o){
    var parse = function(_o){
        var a = [], t;
        for(var p in _o){
            if(_o.hasOwnProperty(p)){
                t = _o[p];
                if(t && typeof t == "object"){
                    a[a.length]= p + ":{ " + arguments.callee(t).join(", ") + "}";
                }
                else {
                    if(typeof t == "string"){
                        a[a.length] = [ p+ ": \"" + t.toString() + "\"" ];
                    }
                    else{
                        a[a.length] = [ p+ ": " + t.toString()];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return a;
    }
    return "{" + parse(o).join(", ") + "}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sure, maybe something like

```
function alertObject(0){
    var str = "";
    for(i in o)
        str += i + " " + o[i] + "\n";
    alert(str);
}
```

Edit :: Note this is just a silly little example.