# JavaScript iterate over [object Object]

Tags: javascript

I am trying to iterate the properties of an object, when I do this:

```
for(var prop in object) {
     if(object.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
          console.log(object[prop]);
     }
}
```

I get [object Object], how I can iterate this?

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Is it a string or an object? An object (which is enumerable) should be expandable in the console view.

Comment: Try `console.dir()` instead of `console.log()`.

Comment: If `console.log` is producing a string result, you're probably using IE. To get around this issue, go to [A Better Browser](http://abetterbrowser.org/) and download an A grade browser with real developer tools such as Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript reflection - generic toString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638979/javascript-reflection-generic-tostring)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're trying to do is to console.log nested objects, you can do this:

`JSON.stringify(object, null, '\t')`